# よう+とする in this sentece

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, volitional-form

I'm reading the book 魔女の宅急便 and this sentece show up.

> 目でそれを追いかけたキキは、オレンジ色の浮きぶくろに乗った坊やとジジが、大きな波に**ひきこまれようとしている**のを見ました。

Now, I have always problem to understand the よう+とする pattern, but generally I understand it like 'To try" similar to the 〜てみる construction.
But in this particular occasion I don't understand what does it meaning. Also, it's attached to the passive voice of the verb 引き込む, and it makes me more confuse.

What's going on here?

Context: Kiki and Jiji are on the beach, and the black cat Jiji is forced to play with a child in the sea, but suddenly a strong wind blow and creates waves.

Comment: verb+ようとする also means 'about to verb'.

Comment: @user3856370 If so, it makes MORE munch sense to me. 勉強しておきます。

Comment: Dup? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28858/45489